# Project From View is being distorted like its adding a perspective even though Im using orthographic view?

Tags: texturing, uv

Im following tutorial about building a city and when I get to [this part](https://youtu.be/NW_djQS_N8U?t=565) where you should use Project From View to get buildings roof top texture from satellite map my projection is aways off, no matter how I scale it.

You can [download the file here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ywbORgnLjJEYwEEkJkHkTnqtDQgciRtn/view?usp=sharing)

After closer inspection it seems like its adding slight perspective to the projection.

This isn't very visible with few smaller object but since I have many buildings it starts to add up and it quickly goes completely off.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

Im using Blender 8.2a, 
2013 MBPr 15"
Intel i7

Comment: Hi and Welcome! I guess you need more geometry for the projection. I suggest share the file using: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hi, thanks. I tried uploading it but its 45MB and the limit is 30 so I uploaded it to my Google Drive instead. You can download it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ywbORgnLjJEYwEEkJkHkTnqtDQgciRtn/view?usp=sharing